# Explicit counter example to Vopěnka's principle in the constructible universe?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

[Vopěnka's principle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Vop%C4%9Bnka%27s+principle) is a large cardinal axiom which has many equivalent formulations. One of them, which I find especially appealing, is the following: if the universe is satisfies Vopěnka's principle then no locally presentable category contains a full subcategory which is large (= a proper class) and discrete (= contains no nonidentity morphisms).

On the other hand, I know that many non-set theorists find the [constructible universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe) $V = L$ to be a very appealing place to do mathematics, for a variety of philosophical reasons.

Now, my understanding is that $V =$ a Vopěnka cardinal is a very Large cardinal axiom, and in particular is inconsistent with $V = L$.

So what I would like is an *explicit* example of a category $C$ which is locally presentable for $V = L$ and a full discrete subcategory of $C$ which is large for $V = L$.

This is very closely related to this previous MO question:
[Can Vopenka's principle be violated definably?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/45602/184)

The difference is that there the OP was asking for a single definable class which violated VP for any universe where VP fails. Here I am asking if such an example can be given in the special case of the constructible universe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a counterexample to Vopenka's principle phrased slightly differently: as "in any proper class of first-order structures, one elementarily embeds into the other."

Working in $V=L$, I claim that $\{L_{\kappa^+}: \kappa\in Card\}$ is a counterexample to Vopenka's principle.

Suppose $\kappa<\lambda$ are cardinals, and $L_{\kappa^+}$ elementarily embeds into $L_{\lambda^+}$, via $j$. Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the set of subsets $X$ of $\kappa$ such that $\kappa\in j(X)$. Clearly $\mathcal{U}$ is an ultrafilter; I claim $\mathcal{U}$ is countably closed. Let $S=\{X_i: i\in\omega\}$ be a sequence of subsets of $\kappa$ such that $X_i\in\mathcal{U}$ for every $i\in\omega$. Note that since $V=L$, the sequence $S$ exists in $L_{\kappa^+}$, and so we can look at $j(S)$. Note first of all that $j(S)$ is an $\omega$-sequence, whose terms are exactly the $j(X_i)$, since $\omega$ can't be moved by $j$. We have $$\forall Y\in j(S), \kappa\in Y,$$ that is, $$\kappa\in\bigcap j(S).$$ But since $S\in L_{\kappa^+}$ and $j$ is elementary, $\bigcap j(S)=j(\bigcap(S))$, so we are done.

So $\mathcal{U}$ is a countably complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$. But this is equivalent to $\kappa$ being measurable, and $V=L$ implies measurable cardinals don't exist.

Comment: Can you explain why $S$ exists in $L_{\kappa^+}$?

Comment: Also, I guess that the proof is supposed to finish via the argument explained at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/226616/146477.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: $S$ is in $L_{\kappa^+}$ via condensation: take some elementary submodel $M$ of $L_\beta$ (where $S\in L_\beta$ - such a $\beta$ exists since $V=L$) with $L_{\kappa+1}\subseteq M$, $S\in M$, and $\vert M\vert=\kappa$. Now by condensation, the transitive collapse $N$ of $M$ is isomorphic to some $L_\gamma$; by cardinality considerations, we have $\gamma<\kappa^+$. But since $L_\kappa\subset M$, we know that the image of $S$ in $N$ is just $S$ itself - so $S\in L_\gamma$, and hence in $L_{\kappa^+}$.

Comment: Re: your second comment, yes, the punchline is that measurables can't exist in $L$; I've edited to make that explicit.

Comment: Meanwhile, it is interesting to note that if Vopenka's principle holds in $V$, when it is larger than $L$, then the class of all $L_{\kappa^+}$ still exists in $V$, and in this case there is an elementary embedding from one $L_{\kappa^+}$ to another. It is just that the embedding does not exist in $L$. So the "counterexample" to VP still exists in $V$, but it is no longer a counterexample there.

Comment: So how can I turn this counter example into a locally presentable category with a large full discrete subcategory, like I originally wanted?

Comment: This might be silly, but: I think condensation lets us show that the category whose objects are the $L_\alpha$s, and whose morphisms are elementary embeddings, is locally presentable?

Comment: My guess would be that the locally presentable category would be something like the category of "first order structures" (not necessarily of the form $L_\alpha$). But now I am going to show the fact that I am not a set theorist because I don't quite know what this means. When I've seen "structure" used it has been in the following context: there is some (first order) language L, and then a structure is a set M with an interpretation of L in M. In your formulation what was the language L? or is it supposed to very?

Comment: In my answer the language was the language $\{\in\}$ of set theory, that is, by "$L_\alpha$" I meant "$(L_\alpha, \in)$".

Comment: Right, of course. Great, so then it is clear to me that the category of structures for this language is a locally presentable category (the morphisms between the $L_\alpha$ are elementary embeddings since they satisfy extensionality, right?). You have constructed a proper class of objects and shown that if that class is not discrete, then there exists a measurable cardinal. Now the main thing that I still don't follow is why $V= L$ is inconsistent with the existence of measurable cardinals.

Comment: Ah, this is a beautiful argument! Roughly: suppose $\mathcal{U}$ is a countably complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$. We may take the ultrapower of $V$ (the whole universe!) mod $\mathcal{U}$; since $\mathcal{U}$ is countably closed, the result object $W$ - as a class-sized $\{\in\}$-structure - is well-founded. Now, this means we can apply the Mostowski collapse and view $W$ as a subclass of $V$. (cont'd)

Comment: Now, we have a problem: we can show that $W$ is a transitive model of ZFC containing all the ordinals, and that $W$ is a proper subclass of $L$. But this is impossible, since $L$ is (provably) the minimal inner model. (Why is $W\subsetneq L$? Well, the image of $\kappa$ under the natural elementary embedding from $V$ into $W$ is strictly larger than $\kappa$ - fun exercise - but if we assume $\kappa$ is the least measurable, this means that $W$ can't tell that $\kappa$ is measurable, so $W$ must not contain $\mathcal{U}$.) See Jech's book for the details of this argument.

Comment: Fun aside: this argument - together with something that looks like the ultrafilter construction in my answer - shows that the existence of a measurable is equivalent to the existence of an elementary embedding of $V$ into some transitive class $M$. This is sort of a "phase transition" in large cardinals: whereas small large cardinals are defined combinatorially, it turns out that elementary embeddings are the right tool for defining/studying large large cardinals, and measurable cardinals sit right in between the two levels.

Comment: Supose that $\kappa= j(\gamma)$ for some $\gamma$. So $U$ is the trivial ultrafilter and $\kappa$ is not necessary measurable.

Comment: @Ândsonjosé Since $\kappa=crit(j)$, that can't happen.